# Visual Studio Code Python Debugger Missing Other Threads in Call Stacks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, odoo, vscode-debugger

## Basic Info

- Environment: Windows 11
- Python Version: 3.8.10
- Use virtual env: Yes
- VSCode Python extension version: v2022.20.2

## Problem

I tried running an Odoo 15 (multi-threaded) application and previously I was able to see that VSCode properly tracked all spawned thread.

However yesterday when I tried to debug my application, I noticed that my breakpoints on code that was supposed to be run on spawned threads weren't hitting (main thread is fine).

After looking at the call stack window, I noticed that what used to be a list of threads are now showing nothing as if there's only 1 thread running.

[image: Call stack on my Odoo 15 program]

Figure 1. Call stack on my Odoo program

So I'm wondering that it has something to do with my VSCode settings, but I'm drawing a blank on which. Interestingly, on my colleague's Linux machine, he can debug and see all the threads fine with VSCode

I've tried to do a clean uninstallation of VSCode and re-installed all extensions manually, but to no avail.

Interestingly, I tried writing a simple threaded program (with threading lib, same as Odoo's) and the call stack showed the multiple threads fine, so I'm lost as of why

[image: Call stack on multi-threaded programs]

Figure 2. Call stack on my simple threaded programs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have an entry in my .env GEVENT_SUPPORT=True.

Once I erased that flag, everything works normal